# Tooltwist Controller - Could not connect to Git Repository

Tags: tooltwist

Trying to run Tooltwist Controller via command line:

./ttc/config/bin/checkLaunchpad.sh controllerTest

Terminate the script and shows below error:

Preparing webdesign project 'gmd'

Check cached Git

Checking GIT Cache for webdesign/gmd  (remote=git@github.com:twistresources/gmd-webdesign.git)

/ControllerV8/payloads/webdesign-projects/gmd/git-repository...remote is set correctly

$ git fetch --all
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: Could not fetch origin

**
** Fatal error: Could not update GIT repository: Fetching origin

**

- removing /ControllerV8/launchpads/controllerTest/build.xml.
- removing /ControllerV8/launchpads/controllerTest/CONFIG_SUMMARY.

Answer (score 1):

This is a git error, most likely caused because you don't have access to the github repository.

On the command line, try changing to the repository directory (/ControllerV8/payloads/webdesign-projects/gmd/git-repository) and running the git command directly:

> $ git fetch --all

From there you should be able to trouble shoot your git command independently of the ToolTwist Controller.

You might need to check your login details and the remote URL you are using, as described in [https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10373248](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10373248/edit). If you change the URL, don't forget to go back and update the Controller.